# How to estimate standard deviation from the smallest and biggest in a batch or batches?

Tags: standard-deviation, extreme-value

I have one or more batches. For each batch I know the size of the biggest item in the batch, and I also know the size of the smallest item in the batch. What would be the best way to estimate the standard deviation of the sizes of the items?

The two variations on this are: a) where I know the size of each batch (which differs from batch to batch) and b) where I do not know the size of any of the batches.

I assume or guess that the best estimate of the mean would be the mean-average of all the figures.

Comment: "The standard deviation of the sizes of the items" is ambiguous.  Are you trying to estimate the SDs of each batch or are you presuming these batches are independent samples of the same process and you would like to estimate its SD?

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this article](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-5-13) by Hozo, S P and Djulbegovic, B and Hozo, I entitled "Estimating the mean and variance from the median, range, and the size of a sample" helpful. As far as I can see you can estimate some of the things you require without the sample size which seems surprising. Since the article is open source and a full answer to all your questions would mean a very long answer I shall not attempt to summarise it.